# Observable best practice

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In my current project I have an observable returning values and I have to update my local variable according to the value returned by the observable.

I see two ways of doing this, either by directly subscribing to my observable, or by using pipable operator.

According to your experience/knowledge, what is the best practice ?

1st approach (directly subscribing):

```
this.myObservable$.subscribe(value=> {
  this.myValue = value;
});
```

2nd approach (using pipable operator):

```
this.myObservable$.pipe(
    tap(value=> this.myValue = value)
  ).subscribe();
```

Comment: I think SO is not the right place to ask it. Try here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Given that the first is simpler, why would you consider the second? Unless you actually need to apply some transformation, the map is redundant.

Comment: The first one is correct. `map` is used to map one value to another which is returned from its callback and it should not perform any side-effects.

Comment: since Observables are lazy - they do not start until subscribed - so you should use .subscribe to do some actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both are valid, but in this particular instance I would use the 1st approach and do the work in the subscribe block. The reason being that the intent is clearer.

"tap" is for doing side-effects, but you are not doing a side-effect here as there is no more logic going on after the tap. What you are doing is using the unwrapped final value to do something, and that is what the subscribe block is for.

Comment: `this.myValue = value;` is literally a side effect. Using `tap` is advised.

Answer (score 0):

I consider doing this within a `pipe` if a local variable has to be mandatory updated. I may have multiple subscriptions for the same observable and I may forget to update the local variable in any one of them. Taking care of this within the Observable is good.

```
myOb$ = this.myObservable$.pipe(
    tap(value=> this.myValue = value)
)
```

Just in your case, If you are not doing any changes in Observable, you can use, `tap()` instead of `map()`

Consider you want to update a variable of a class where the Observable exists not where it is subscribed then this is the way you go. Say, an Observable exists in a Service and multiple components are subscribing to it, after every emission, a variable of the service has got to be updated.

If the local variable belongs to the class subscribing the Observable, then of course there is no point in doing it within the pipe.